# python takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python, django

getting this error in django:

```
alertmenewsignup() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Here's my code

```
info = { ...stuff ... }
updateme = blablaEmail()
updateme.alertmenewsignup(info)

class blablaEmail(object)
    def __init__:
        ...stuff....
    def alertmenewsignup(self, **kwargs):
```

I have declared self and **kwargs in the function and yet it claims to only take one argument?

Comment: `**kwargs` holds keyword arguments, and you've supplied a positional argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `**` for keyword arguments.  While a single `*` are for positional arguments.

```
def alertmenewsignup(self, **kwargs)
```

would be called

```
updateme.alertmenewsignup(info=info)
```

While

```
def alertmenewsignup(self, *args)
```

can be called with positional arguments

```
updateme.alertmenewsignup(info)
```

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus: Yes, sorry I fixed that.

Comment: I'm really confused now. so what IS **kwargs used for then??? I thought it would be for a dictionary to be passed as an argument?

Comment: I always thought even "positional arguments" could be used "out of order" with alertme(info=info, tim=tim) even if you defined it as alertme(tim,info)

Comment: @StrikePricer no, Python doesn't invent argument names for you like that.

Comment: @StrikePricer When you explicitly declare positional parameters with names, you can specify them either with positional or keyword arguments when you're calling the function. When you declare **kwargs, kwargs holds the dictionary of "leftover" keyword arguments that aren't mapped to explicitly declared positional arguments.

Comment: so in the answer above, info would just be a variable name in the function, but NOT be found in the alertme(self, **kwargs) top line definition?